# How to Remove publishing options joomla front end create article?

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5. I want to remove/hide Publishing, Language and Metadata options from front-end(Create Article) so that users of the website can just enter the subject and content for their article and submit the article.
Another question - How can I Publish Joomla article programatically?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done as these fields are part of the Joomla! Article Manager form. These are the core functionality of Joomla. But if you really want it,They can probably be removed using a "Template override method" -

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core